# SocketIO unintended behaviour when joining rooms

Tags: python, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am working with Python/SocketIO, but I don't fully understand the Join behaviour. In the example below, I expect a client to emit a join message to the server, and receive a 'server post' message once. However, if I open 2 client pages simultaneously, when I reload one, the other receives a 'server post' message a second time, and hence it appends the 'server post' json to the page.

For context this is for a chat app which reloads old messages on page load.

Python server:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room
from flask_restful import Api
import json


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/')
def sessions():
    return render_template('session.html')

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    myjson={'message':'connect'}
    emit('my connect',myjson,type=json)

@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(json):
    room='abc'
    join_room(room)
    myjson={'message':'join'}
    emit('server post',myjson,type=json, room=room, broadcast=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

Client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <div id="message_holder"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

  socket.on( 'connect', function() {
    socket.emit('join',{})
  })

  socket.on('my connect', function(msg) {
    $('#message_holder').append('<p>'+msg.message+'</p>')
  })

  socket.on('server post', function(msg) {
    $('#message_holder').append('<p>'+msg.message+'</p>')
  })

</script>
```

In this example, I would expect the page to show 'connect' and 'join', regardless of any external activity, but 'join' is repeated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know python, so it's a bit hard to understand what's going on, but i see you have emit('server post',myjson,type=json, room=room, broadcast=False). This emit method, is it the one of the IO object, or the specific socket? If the first is true, then it emits the message to all connected sockets, therefore creating the duplication. You can take a look at this cheat sheet, if you understand Javascript: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

Comment: When you open two clients you will have both on the "abc" room. You are emitting the "server post" message to the room, so all clients will get it. If you want to send "server post" just to this one client, but not the other, then use `room=request.sid`, and then the message will only go to the client that just joined the room.

Comment: Thanks both. Miguel that's the one I was looking for and it works. I want to use 'server post' to keep the treatment of the message consistent and chronological, so this is the solution I need, thanks.